# Пользователь вводит два числа(высоту и ширину), а получает в ответ шахматную доску.Не могу понять почему не работает код

Tags: javascript

```js
 function chessDeck(form){
   var height = form.Height.value;
   var widht = form.Width.value; 
   var arr [][] = new Array([height][widht]);
   var firstPoint = '*';
   var secondPoint = '#';
   var point = '*';
   var column = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
     arr[i][j] = point;
     column = arr[i][j];
     if(point == firstPoint){
      point = secondPoint;
     }
     else if(point == secondPoint){
      point = firstPoint;
     }
    }
    if(column == firstPoint){
     point = secondPoint;
    }
    else if(point == secondPoint){
     point = firstPoint;
    }
   }
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
     document.write(arr[i][j]);
    }
   }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <p>
    <input type="text" name="Height">
   </p>
   <p>
    <input type="text" name="Width">
   </p>
   <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="chessDeck(form)">
  </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Практически уверен что ошибка в создании матрицы. Подскажите что я не так делаю.

Comment: `document.write(arr[i][о])` - что есть `о`?

Comment: j, прошу прощения

Comment: сделайте [не]работающий пример, который можно запустить - в редакторе вопроса кнопка "Фрагмент кода на ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работает по причине неправильного объявления массива и вывода информации.

Поправил логику, вывод и объявление массива.

```
function chessDeck(form){
    var height = form.Height.value;
    var widht = form.Width.value;
    var arr = [];
    var firstPoint = "*";
    var secondPoint = "#";
    var point = "*";
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < widht; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = point;
            if (point == firstPoint)
                point = secondPoint;
            else if (point == secondPoint)
                point = firstPoint;
        }
        if (widht % 2 == 0)
            point = (point == firstPoint ? secondPoint : firstPoint);
        else
            point = (point == firstPoint ? firstPoint : secondPoint);
    }
    var inn = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < widht; j++) {
            inn = inn + arr[i][j] + "|";
        }
        inn = inn + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inn;
}
```

Вывод:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="Height">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="Width">
      </p>
        <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="chessDeck(form)">
    </form>
    <p id="demo">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рад помочь

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте `document.write` после загрузки страницы.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

> *Note:* as `document.write` writes to the document stream, calling
>   `document.write` on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls
>   `document.open`, which will clear the document.
>
> *Хозяйке на заметку:* так как `document.write` пишет в поток (stream)
>   документа, вызов `document.write` закрытого (загруженного - loaded)
>   документа автоматически вызывает `document.open`, что очищает
>   документ.

И разберитесь с логикой для четного количества столбцов.

```js
function chessDeck(form){
  var height = form.Height.value;
  var widht = form.Width.value; 
  var arr = [];
  var firstPoint = '*';
  var secondPoint = '#';
  var point = '*';
  var column = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < height; i++){
    arr[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < widht; j++){
      arr[i][j] = point;
      column = arr[i][j];
      if(point == firstPoint) {
        point = secondPoint;
      } else if(point == secondPoint) {
        point = firstPoint;
      }
    }
    if(column == firstPoint){
      point = secondPoint;
    } else if(point == secondPoint){
      point = firstPoint;
    }
  }

  console.log("[");
  for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
    console.log("  " + JSON.stringify(arr[j]));
  console.log("]");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="Height">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="Width">
  </p>
  <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="chessDeck(form)">
</form>
```